# Creating a numpy array from an integer

Tags: arrays, numpy

I created a multiplication table from an integer input using numpy. I created a list from the integer, and created an array with the shape of the integer, but it seems I'm ending up doing things the non-numpy way. Is there a more numpionic way of doing this?

TY

```
def multiplication_table(n):
    import numpy as np
    base = list(range(1, n+1))
    array_shell = np.zeros(shape=(n,n), dtype=int)
    array_shell[0] = base
    for row in range(1,len(base)):
        array_shell[row][0] = base[row]
    for row in range(1, len(base)):
        for idx in range(1, len(base)):
            array_shell[row][idx] = base[idx]*array_shell[row][0]
    return (array_shell)

my_int = 8
print(multiplication_table(my_int))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach that uses NumPy's powerful [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) feature -

```
def multiplication_table_vectorized(n):
    base = np.arange(n)+1
    return base[:,None]*base
```

Runtime test -

```
In [33]: n = 100

In [34]: np.allclose(multiplication_table(n),multiplication_table_vectorized(n))
Out[34]: True

In [35]: %timeit multiplication_table(n)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.1 ms per loop

In [36]: %timeit multiplication_table_vectorized(n)
10000 loops, best of 3: 58.9 µs per loop
```

Explanation -

Let's take a toy example for explaining things here.

```
In [72]: n = 4 # Small n for toy example

In [73]: base = np.arange(n)+1 # Same as original: "base = list(range(1, n+1))"

In [74]: base                  # Checkback
Out[74]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [75]: base[:,None]   # Major thing happening as we extend base to a 2D array
                        # with all elements "pushed" as rows (axis=0) and thus
                        # creating a singleton dimension along columns (axis=1)
Out[75]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])

In [76]: base[:,None]*base    # Broadcasting happens as elementwise multiplications
                              # take place between 2D extended version of 'base' 
                              # and original 'base'. This is our desired output.

                              # To visualize a broadcasting :
                              # |--------->
                              # |
                              # |
                              # |
                              # V

Out[76]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12],
       [ 4,  8, 12, 16]])
```

For more information and examples on `broadcasting`, there's nothing better than the [`official docs`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). `Broadcasting` is one of the best vectorization tools around available with `NumPy` that allows for such automatic expansions.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. Could you please explain how the return makes it work? I understand making the base an ndarray, but I'm confused on how the return/math works to populate.

Comment: @TASCSolutions See if the added comments help to understand what's going on in there.

Comment: Yes I see clearly now:  I needed to arange my integer so numpy can use it and the base[:,None] replaced my for loop to get the vertical row and then broadcasting and basic math did the rest.

Comment: @TASCSolutions You got it! Good job on it.

Answer (score 0):

One "numpyonic" way to approach this would be as a matrix multiplication (of a column vector with a row vector):

```
base = np.arange(my_int)
array = base.reshape((my_int,1)) * base
```

Comment: Thanks, it appears I need to take another numpy tutorial, these solutions are much faster and cleaner than my hybrid approach.

Comment: don't worry if you don't get it straight away, it took me a very long time for this way of thinking to "click" for me